# Issue running python selenium web search

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do a simple google search using selenium python, but when I execute the script I'm getting the following error.

I noticed that as soon as chrome is loaded I am getting the 'before you continue with google' popup, which might be part of the problem, how can I bypass this or accept cookies?

Heres my code,

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

# Create an instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to Google
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Find the search input element and enter the query
search_input = driver.find_element("name", "q")
search_input.send_keys('BBC News')

driver.quit()
```

Heres the error I am getting,

```
/Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python           /Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ChatgptTest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ChatgptTest.py", line 12, in <module>
search_input.send_keys('BBC News')
  File "/Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-     packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
self._execute(
File "/Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site- packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Users/johna/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.92)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver    0x0000000103b54ae8 chromedriver + 4958952
1   chromedriver    0x0000000103b4c7b3 chromedriver + 4925363
2   chromedriver    0x000000010370e051 chromedriver + 475217
3   chromedriver    0x0000000103749c2c chromedriver + 719916
4   chromedriver    0x00000001037490f6 chromedriver + 717046
5   chromedriver    0x0000000103777c12 chromedriver + 908306
6   chromedriver    0x00000001037438f1 chromedriver + 694513
7   chromedriver    0x0000000103777dce chromedriver + 908750
8   chromedriver    0x000000010379325b chromedriver + 1020507
9   chromedriver    0x00000001037779e3 chromedriver + 907747
10  chromedriver    0x0000000103741aef chromedriver + 686831
11  chromedriver    0x000000010374300e chromedriver + 692238
12  chromedriver    0x0000000103b109ad chromedriver + 4680109
13  chromedriver    0x0000000103b15c12 chromedriver + 4701202
14  chromedriver    0x0000000103b1c79f chromedriver + 4728735
15  chromedriver    0x0000000103b16b7a chromedriver + 4705146
16  chromedriver    0x0000000103ae927e chromedriver + 4518526
17  chromedriver    0x0000000103b36908 chromedriver + 4835592
18  chromedriver    0x0000000103b36a87 chromedriver + 4835975
19  chromedriver    0x0000000103b4600f chromedriver + 4898831
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x00007fff728b7109 _pthread_start + 148
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x00007fff728b2b8b thread_start + 15
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I was expecting that it would launch google and search for BBC News and then end script.

Comment: This can happen if the element is not yet loaded on the page or is not visible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting a accept cookies popup when loading chrome, how do I pass this step, or accept the cookies? Many thanks for your help btw

Comment: Please read this [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), add minimal code

Comment: I've just updated the post with the code I am running..hope this helps